cuerpo de soclicitud post en postman
Buen dia, tengo el siguiente problema: Tengo una entidad ALUMNO en java que tiene una relación 1:1 con otra entidad USER, cuando quiero crear un ALUMNO en postman por medio de una solicitud, además de los datos propios del ALUMNO quiero enviar los del USER, pero no logro configurar bien el cuerpo de la solicitud. ¿Alguien me podria ayudar? De momento lo intente hacer así:
{
   "alumnos":{
    "documento":"456987",
    "nombre":"saul",
    "apellido":"garcia",
    "email":"correo2@gmail.com",
    "usuarios":{
        "username":"saulito",
        "password":"asdw"
    }
   }
}


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Si no sabemos a donde queres llegar, no podemos ayudarte con lo que queres mandar...

Tu pregunta no se puede responder sin saber qué es soportado por el API a la que estás enviando esta estructura, qué error estás obteniendo y más. Por favor lee [ask].
